# How to show $X_{n} Y_{n} \rightarrow_{1} X Y$ given $E|X_n|^r \rightarrow E|X|^r, E|Y_n|^s\rightarrow E|Y|^s$

Tags: probability, lebesgue-integral

The full setting of the question is:

> Let $X_{n}, Y_{n}(n=1,2, \ldots), X$, and $Y$ be random variables on the probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal{A}, P) .$ If $E\left|X_{n}\right|^{r} \rightarrow E|X|^{r}$ for some $r>0$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$, we denote that $X_{n} \rightarrow_{r} X .$ Suppose that $X_{n} \rightarrow_{r} X, Y_{n} \rightarrow_{s} Y$, and $\frac{1}{r}+\frac{1}{s}=1$ for $r>1$
> and $s>1$. Please show that $X_{n} Y_{n} \rightarrow_{1} X Y$ (i.e., $\left.E\left|X_{n} Y_{n}-X Y\right| \rightarrow 0\right)$.

This is a practice question I am taken to get myself to know better about the convergence of moment and also inequality. I think fro the set up I should use holder's inequality, but the problem is $E\left|X_{n}\right|^{r} \rightarrow E|X|^r$ is a weaker condition than $E|X_n-X|^r\rightarrow 0$. If I set

$$E|X_nY_n-XY|=E|X_nY_n-X_nY+X_nY-XY|=E|X_n(Y_n-Y)+Y(X_n-X)|\leq||X||_r||Y_n-Y||_s+||Y||_s||X_n-X||$$ I am unable to make the limit goes to $0$ for the reason I just explained. Did I misunderstand the idea of convergence in mode or there's other way to complete the prove?

Comment: Your notation is inconsistent between $\to_r$ (which ask for convergence of the absolute expectations) and $\to_1$ (which asks for L1 convergence).

Comment: To add to @WillM.s comment, the claim with this new definition of r convergence wouldn't hold. (X_n s don't converge to Xs in any useful sense, so it is very hard to say anything about the limit.) More than likely, they just defined it incorrectly, and it is the strong condition that you note in your question body that is the correct

Comment: Here's a simple counterexample to what you're trying to prove: Let $P(X=1)=P(X=0) = 1/2$ and set $X_n=Y_n=X$ and $Y=1-X$.  We don't even have $E|X_nY_n| \to E|XY|$.  I assume $\to_r$ is supposed to be $L^r$ convergence everywhere.

Comment: @BrianMoehring Thank you so much! I am very confused because of the notation too! I am going to inform my teacher I think there is typo here

Comment: @JoZ if the original question happens to be convergences in $\mathscr{L}_r$  and $\mathscr{L}_s,$ you can use Hölder's inequality and what your wrote carries over. (You probably already know this.)